# LAPACK wrappers for C/C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, lapack

I would like to use `Visual Studio 2008`, programming in C++, but would also like to use LAPACK power, Is there any wrapper so I can use `LAPACK` in `Visual Studio 2008`.

Comment: It's been a few days and you haven't accepted an answer or commented negatively on any of the answers below. Is there something more you're looking for beyond what the answers offer?

Comment: Thank you, I have not been around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [CLAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/clapack/index.html), [lapack++](http://www.netlib.org/lapack++/), or its supposed successor [Template Numerical Toolkit](http://math.nist.gov/tnt/).

Answer (score 4):

[Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) works great for me. Good API, excellent performance.

Comment: Indeed, Armadillo is more modern than lapack++, as it extensively uses expression templates. Its syntax also closely resembles Matlab.

Answer (score 3):

I use this:
https://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/numeric_bindings/

careful not to use the old v1:
http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/binding-v1-vs-sandbox-numeric-bindings-td3036149.html

Comment: These are bindings that can be used with the Boost uBlas linear algebra library (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm).

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use a commercial product, then I can recommend Intel Math Kernel library. It will cost you 400$ for a single user license, but you get a very fast implementation that is optimized for Intel processors.

Answer (score 1):

LAPACK provides its own C bindings [`<lapacke.h>`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapacke.html) since version 3.4.0.

There are two binding options for each LAPACK function, either a low-level wrapper that just mimics the FORTRAN function call or a higher-level wrapper that takes care of all the workspace memory allocation for you.

Another nice touch is that you can choose whether to use column-major or row-major ordering now.